# MySQL Workbench Connection

Tags: mysql, connection, mysql-workbench

I have a question regarding connecting `MySQL Workbench` to `Mariadb`. 
The only way for me to connect is through `SSH`.

I have to login to server as `user@server` and then execute `sudo -s` to get root. Only then I am able to connect to the Mariadb.

Is there a way to make `MySQL Workbench` to function. It would not connect because I have to switch user to root somehow in the process of connecting.

Here is what i do in `PuTTY` to connect:

```
login as: johnny
johnny@norton password:
Last login: Mon Aug 29 09:18:26 2016 from 
[johnny@norton ~]$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for johnny:
[root@norton ~]# mysql -p
Enter password:
mysql>
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need local root access to connect to the database server? That sounds _very_ strange...

Comment: I don't know. If i try to connect without it the following happen:

login as: johnny
johnny@nortonpassword:
Last login: Mon Aug 29 11:02:37 2016
[johnny@norton ~]$ mysql -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'

Comment: Well, you do realize that you try to connect with two different account names? Which one is the correct one you actually _want_ to connect with? Probably `root`, but note that the mysql root acount has _nothing_ to do with the systems root account. So try this without being root in the system: `mysql -u root -p` (and start reading the documentation please...)

Comment: Here is what i get:
[johnny@norton ~]$ cd /
[johnny@norton /]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Hm, your client appears to connect through the file system socket listener mysql sets up, not through the network layer. And that socket appears to only be available to the root account... What about `mysql -h localhost -u root -p` or `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` ?

Comment: Or add the result of `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` to your question above.

Comment: [johnny@norton /]$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
[johnny@norton /]$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
ls: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, but there is something fishy here. Could it be that you are executing those commands on your local system, not on the one the mysql server runs on?

Comment: It is definitely on a server side. I have been breaking my head over this for a while. I can connect if I do sudo -s and i can sun all the queries without any problem. But only if I'm root. how can this be...

Comment: Just to check I've understood are you on windows trying to connect to a remote server using an ssh client such as putty?

Comment: @JamesScott The OP clearly states that the topic is to connect the MySQL Workbench to the mysql server. It has a buildin ssh wrapper client.

Comment: That is correct. I'm on windows. The only way for me to access mysql is if i login through putty and then sudo -s and only then connect to mysql. I was hoping to connect MySQL workbench, and I can't because I'm forced to switch to root at during the process.

Comment: Why don't you forward the port on putty using the ssh commands? Then you can log in through workbench using 127.0.0.1:3307 (port is an example, assume you're reserving 3306 for a true local instance). Can answer back with screenshots if you think this might work

Comment: San you please post the screenshots. I will try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this please:

Setup putty as normal, but under ssh and tunnels try the following (This will connect port 3307 on your local computer to port 3306 on your remote computer - ensure there are no firewalls blocking these if you have any issues):

[image: putty add tunnel 1]

Don't forget to click 'add' so the port forward appears in the box above:

[image: putty add tunnel 2]

Then setup the MySQL connection as if it was a local connection and you should be able to connect

[image: putty add tunnel 3]

Regards,

James